# Type issue with prolog

Tags: prolog

I wanted to create a "function" that "returns" the even elements of a list :

```
elements_pairs([], []).
elements_pairs([H|T], R) :- H mod 2 =:= 0, elements_pairs(T,Rn), R is [H|Rn].
elements_pairs([H|T], R) :- not(H mod 2 =:= 0), elements_pairs(T,Rn), R is Rn.
```

This `elements_pairs([1,3,4,6], R)` produces this error:

> ERROR: Type error: `[]` expected, found `[4|6]` (a compound) ("x" must hold one character)
>
> ERROR: In: ERROR:   [11] _3884 is [4|6] ERROR:   [10]
> elements_pairs([4,6],_3918) at path/tp.pl:21 ERROR:    [9]
> elements_pairs([3,4|...],_3956) at path/tp.pl:21 ERROR:    [8]
> elements_pairs([1,3|...],_3994) at path/tp.pl:21 ERROR:    [7]

What's wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: `is` is for maths. use `=` instead.

Comment: @TomasBy Thanks !